# Is it grammatically incorrect to say "I speak a bit German"?

Tags: grammaticality, synonyms, syntax

Do they all mean the same?

1. I speak a bit German
2. I speak a little bit of German
3. I speak German a bit.
4. I speak some German.
5. I speak a little German.

I have been told 1 is incorrect. 
I am trying to learn English through online resources and apps and all these little things are driving me crazy. Any help is appreciated. And I apologize if its been already asked before.

Comment: The first sentence needs an *of* : "I speak a bit **of** German."

Answer (score 3):

#1 is incorrect.  In a transitive sentence like "I speak ______", the object has to be a noun or noun phrase.  **A bit** is a noun, so it works as the object, but if you want to describe the kind of bit, you have to use *of*, as in "a bit *of* German".  You can't just ram the noun *a bit* and the proper noun *German* together without any kind of preposition or conjunction; *a bit German* is not a correct noun phrase.

---

You might ask, "Why do I see sentences like *'He looks a bit German'* then?"  The answer is that in that sentence, *German* is an adjective, not a proper noun, and *a bit* is modifying the adjective.

Comment: +1. Didn't see your answer  at first.